# openstack kilo installation through devstack mysql issue:

Tags: openstack, devstack

I faced following error while installing devstack on by ubuntu 14.04.3 virtual machine :[image]

i would like to know how to solve the mysql error i faced

Comment: You should always type out the error in the post, so that google can index it and other people who search for this same error can find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
./unstack.sh
./clean.sh
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
```

then check if there is any mysql process is running `ps -ef | grep mysql`, if there is any unexpected mysql process, kill it.

Finally

```
./stack.sh
```

Comment: Some more context about how this answer addresses the error in question, why this error happens, and what/why this procedure fixes it is important for giving a great answer.

Comment: according to the picture only question, I can only provide a solution instead of some detailed what/why/when. I'm a normal dev, not God